# How to create job/pipeline script in Jenkins-on-jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have created account in the below Jenkins URL

https://ci.jenkins.io

I can able to create a view from the above URL.But when I try to create a new Job/pipeline script it is throwing the below error..

> User is missing job/create permission

Note: I am trying to create a job in Jenkins-on-Jenkins.

Thanks.

Comment: So.. because you probably don't have permissions to do so? Are you in touch with the [jenkins-infra](https://github.com/jenkins-infra/jenkins-infra) folks like [rtyler](https://twitter.com/agentdero?lang=en)? I think that you're trying to do some weird thing..

Comment: I think I don't have permission.Am I missing anything here..@StephenKing

Comment: What do you want to do? You seem to be kind of aware that this is the Jenkins installation of all Jenkins installations - but do you want a repository for a new Jenkins plugin or similar that you develop as open source? Or do you want to run your company's CI jobs there?

Comment: It is possible to create or run Jobs there...if it so how we can do this ..when I am trying to create it's showing the above highlighted error

Comment: This is the installation that is used for the Jenkins open source project itself. Only jobs related to that project can run there. It is not for playing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I really think that this leads to nothing and the author should accept that he is simply not allowed to use that Jenkins installation. Not all stuff on the Internet is free for all.

Comment: Thanks very much for your support and guidance. I thought like we can create a job there. Anyway Thanks.